# Show a list of posts in category page Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

So basically I'm trying to show the list of posts of a category page. I need to do it dynamically, so each category page has it own posts list. I ended up with this code, but it shows all post from all categories.

```html
<?php

$lastposts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5
));

if ($lastposts)
{
    foreach ($lastposts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        
    <?php
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: So pass a `category` parameter to `get_posts` then ...?

Comment: For instance if I have site.com/category/category-x in this page I want to show only the list of posts correlated to category-x not the full posts like you get with parameter the_content();. With the code I posted it shows all posts from all categories

Comment: Yes, because you did not specify yet, which categories you want posts from. Which is kinda the reason I told you that's what you should do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution

```html
<div class="entry-content">
        <div class=" my-5">         
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="section-heading__title" rel="noopener">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></h2>
            <div>
                <div class="attachment__description my-2"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                <hr/>
                <span class="uppercase">Published on <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                <span><?php echo site_posted_by();?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).